# vim - how to keep cursor position while copying text

Tags: windows, vim, editor

I am (having to) using gvim in windows. I was used to the linux environment where when I select text using mouse the cursor position wont change. Now , with gvim in windows,

My problem is something like this -

1. while I am editing in line 6
2. and when I am having to copy "hellovim" from line 3
3. and when I click with mouse on "hellovim" to copy it
4. then the cursor gets moved to "hellovim" on line 3
5. where as I would like the cursor to stay on line 6

How can I do this

Comment: With your hand on the mouse (which is frowned upon by most Vim users), why don't you just use it to move the cursor back?!

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118414/vim-how-to-keep-cursor-position-while-copying-text; please don't post the same question to multiple sites in parallel!

Comment: Can you tell me the right place to ask this question ? I expected an answer in the unix forum , i didnt get one soon enough, it was then that I was tempted to ask in stackoverflow where I got faster responses - Whats wrong with asking the question in two forums anyway if its relevant ?  Is there a stackexchange policy which says   that I should not do it ?

Comment: If you expect an answer in one hour (that's the coarse difference reported at the sites), that's overly optimistic / impatient, isn't it? I'd personally would find it okay if you had cross-posted _after a few days_, with _cross-links on both questions_. Anything else is disrespectful of the people answering and also those searching for answers IMO.

Comment: While I admit that I was impatient , that was not the reason why I posted the question in both places- it was because I was not sure where I will get a better answer, both sites have got vim tags and I got different solutions from different people on both sites. And yes, I missed to put the cross-links , that was a mistake. I will take care next time , but I am still not sure whether its allowed or not allowed as per stack exchange policy ! :)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, using the mouse to select text is against the philosophy of Vim, and prevents you from becoming really productive with the editor. But if you "have to" use (G)Vim against your choice, that's fine, Vim can accommodate you:

The key is *marks*. Some are automatic, for example **the `` `. `` command takes you back to the last edit position**.

If you used a *jump* command (like `3G`) to navigate to the other position,  **``` `` ``` takes you back to the previous jump position**. The `Ctrl-O` command does the same, but can also take you further back.

You can also manually set (`ma`) and go back (`` `a ``) to jumps; like registers, Vim has many (`a-z`) of them.

Answer (score 2):

Just press CTRL-O to jump back to line 6.

See this tip:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were using vim in a terminal window on Linux, not gvim.  I think there is a terminal version of vim for Windows, but you say you have to use gvim.

In a terminal, vim does not control the mouse nor the selection.  You can get similar behavior in gvim with

```
:set mouse=
```

Then you can select text with the mouse; for instance, double-click to select a word.  The problem is how to copy and paste this text.  By default, the only way seems to be to use CTRL-Y in Command-line mode to copy; since you are starting in Insert mode, you could use <kbd>CTRL-O</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>CTRL-Y</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd>.  If this is your only use of CTRL-C in Insert mode, then you could

```
:imap <C-C> <C-O>:<C-Y><CR>
```

Pasting is easier, depending on the settings of the `'guioptions'` and `'clipboard'` options.

```
:help 'mouse'
:help 'mousemodel'
:help gui-mouse-modeless
```